# Create points (gl_Points) and show sequentially in modern OpenGL - PyOpenGL

Tags: opengl, points, particles, vertices

I have been using OpenGL for a while now and continue to stay positive about making progress. However, I now have an issue that I have been unable to solve and it's taking a while. So, the issue is that I would like to:

- Create points on screen sequentially (to appear every second for example)
- Move these points independently

So far I have 2 methods on paper and that is to upload all vertices to a VBO and make each point visible (draw). The other method I had in mind was to create an empty VBO (set to NULL) and upload data per point.

Note, I want to transform these points independent of each other - can a uniform still be used? If so how can I set this up to draw point - transform - draw point - transform.

If I'm going about this completely wrong or there is a better, more improved method then please say so.

Many thanks!

Comment: In second VBO fill it with transformation matrix for each point and use instancing while drawing so you can index matrix from second  VBO using gl_InstanceId. This is efficient way to do simple would be send matries from second VBO as per vertex attribute.

Comment: Hi Paritosh, I appreciate your comments. I am aware of instancing and transform feedback methods and I will likely use these eventually. I wanted to know if I can get points showing and moving independently without those methods so I have a good baseline comparison to compare frame rates etc eventually. So can I do this with a simple VBO (static / stream / dynamic) setup or is this something I can only do using instancing / TF? Many thanks

Comment: You can send matrices packed in VBO as per vetex attribute. Just like you send normal or color.

Comment: Hi Paritosh, I've managed to get the points to show up sequentially correctly but still struggling with getting the matrices to work.Could you perhaps provide a link to a clear example or write some pseudo code? Many thanks

Comment: I have this demo which is actually OIT but I draw lot of objects using instancing.

https://github.com/PixelClear/Order-Independent-Trasparency/blob/master/TeslaCompute/TeslaComputeMain.cpp

In this file look for ```BuildLinkedList()``` function which has code for instancing and can look at how ```gl_InstanceId``` is used in shaders.